# Error in nested form and twig display

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I have a problem with errors display in my twig templates.
Here is my twig with one nested form `form.pictures` :

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{% if not form.vars.valid %}
    <div class="flash-errors-wrapper">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        <div class="form-errors">{{ form_errors(form.pictures) }}</div>
    </div>
{% endif %}

{% for formChild in form.pictures %}
<div class="child">
    {% if not formChild.vars.valid %}
        <div class="flash-errors-wrapper">
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            <div class="form-errors">{{ form_errors(form.picture) }}</div>
            <div class="form-errors">{{ form_errors(form.caption) }}</div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    {{ form_widget(formChild.picture) }}
    {{ form_widget(formChild.caption) }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

After submission, when a child form is non valid, my parent form is not valid too.
Problem is that it display empty div on top like :

```
    <div class="flash-errors-wrapper">
        <div class="form-errors"></div>
    </div>
```

I don't want that because css exist on `flash-errors-wrapper` class so style is applied.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly need to check if one child form is not valid when you check if the parent form is valid. One way to do it would be (Untested, it may need some adaptation):

```
{% if not form.vars.valid %}
    {% set all_childs_valid = True %}
    {% for formChild in form.pictures %}
       {% if not formChild.vars.valid %}
          {% set all_childs_valid = False %}
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if all_childs_valid %}
    <div class="flash-errors-wrapper">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        <div class="form-errors">{{ form_errors(form.pictures) }}</div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Good, I adapted it for my case. I have a parent twig template `base.html.twig`. I set a variable `children` in child template. if the variable is defined (reference to `form.pictures`), I do the verification...

Answer (score 0):

I usually display form errors just as described in [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#customizing-error-output):

```
 {% if errors|length > 0 %}
    <ul>
        {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: Thx but it's not what I try to do.